# git mergetool doesn't 3-way merge properly

Tags: git, git-rebase, meld

I've started using meld as my `merge.tool`. It's worked okay so far, but I'm having a problem with a three-way merge today.

In MyBranch's file.txt I've added code `ME`:

```
A
B
ME
D
E
```

Meanwhile, master has added code `THEM_1` and `THEM_2`. I run `git rebase master`. This is what file.txt looks when the rebase pauses:

```
  A
  THEM_1
  B
<<<<<<< HEAD
  ME
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
  THEM_2
>>>>>>> My patch name
  D
  E
```

THEM_2 should come before ME in the merge, so the obvious merge is

```
A
THEM_1
B
THEM_2
ME
D
E
```

But when I run `git mergetool` which opens meld, none of the three version have `THEM_1`. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to reproduce your situation.

If I do `git checkout me; git merge theirs; git mergetool -t meld`, I get the following:

```
local | merge | remote
------+-------+-------
A     | A     | A
B     | B     | THEM_1
ME    | D     | B
D     | E     | THEM_2
E     |       | D
      |       | E
```

(This is exactly the content of the two branches and the common parent in the middle.)

If I do `git checkout me; git rebase theirs; git mergetool -t meld`, I get the same with local and remote swapped.

In both cases you can add THEM_1 simply by clicking. For the conflict at ME/THEM_2, you can add one side with a click, but have to add the other manually in the middle frame.

Have a look at `kdiff3` it's a much nicer tool for solving merge conflicts.

Be aware that a rebase with conflicts tends to be tricky if multiple commits are to be rebased.

Comment: My problem is that for an unknown reason THEM_1 did not appear in either of the branches using meld (and of course neither in the common parent) for this particular commit. I will give kdiff3 a try, thanks.

Comment: the other problem is that "add it simply by clicking" is a laborious pain frought with user error when there are dozens upon dozens of changes in master since the last rebase and gits internal mergetool has allready done things properly and put them there. So why isn't the middle file reflective of the state of the "pause" file? and is there a way to set it up so that meld will make this happen. I.E. always add branch/HEAD~1 as the common ancestor or something?